# StarTeam Integration with Visual Studio under windows Vista is being closed?

Tags: starteam

When the Solution is checked out from the StarTeam project to the local working folder, the Visual Studio 2005 IDE is closed automatically.

Is there any patch for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like *Visual Studio 2005 IDE* doesn't like its solutions being switched while it is running.

Suggest you start by checking-out the relevant Solution, and only then launch the *Visual Studio 2005 IDE*.